# Code runs correctly but doesn't work when there are more number of brackets

Tags: c++, string

The question is to check if the string contains balanced brackets or Not. This code works fine when the string is `{{()}}` but not when `{{(())}}`.  Also, I wanted to run test cases like when I insert while loop it to check various test-cases it doesn't work properly.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        int i,n;
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        n = sizeof(s);
        int c=0,c1=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='{'||s[i]=='('||s[i]=='['){
                c++;
            }
            else if(s[i]=='}'||s[i]==')'||s[i]==']'){
                c1++;
            }
        }
        if(c==c1)
        {
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
        }
        else{
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n = sizeof(s);` is incorrect. The length of a `std::string` is `s.size()` or `s.length()`.

Comment: While the code block hides it, you still shouldn't use `using namespace std;`. Generally it does not cause errors but can lead to pain very quickly.

Comment: @Vrundali Navadiya, I assume that you know this is a coding problem from websites such as Leetcode, hackerrank, codility, etc...,  right ? Have you searched those websites for the solution or maybe, just google in general ?

Comment: Yeah but since my code logic is different from those discussions the only problem with my code is while loop that isn't working properly I couldn't find answer from those solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Use three separate stacks for {, [, and (. Push whenever you encounter left part and pop when you encounter right part. All stacks should be empty when they are balanced. You need to write some additional logic to check mixed up symbols.